# How Can I access the first result?

Tags: php

```
    $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT commercial FROM Channels WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'");
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tmp))
    {
     echo $row['commercial'];
    }
```

I only want to access the first element.
not in a while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mysql_fetch_row` to retrieve the value like that ...

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($tmp);
$commercial = $row['commercial'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just remove your while loop then. This will get the first (actually current) row:

```
$tmp = mysql_query("SELECT commercial FROM Channels WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tmp);
echo $row['commercial'];
```

Another option is to use mysql_result:

```
$tmp = mysql_query('..');
$row = mysql_result($tmp, 0);
echo $row['commercial'];
```

Side note: If you only need one row, add `LIMIT 1` to your query.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just the first element, why don't you append `LIMIT 1` to your query ?